# Angular 4. A series of http requests get cancelled

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

When I try to make multiple http requests via http service in Angular 4,
previous request get cancelled in Chrome (but they reach the server).
Example:

```
const obs1 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/transitions`);
const obs2 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/states`);
obs1.subscribe();  
obs2.subscribe(); // this will cancel obs1's http request
```

But if I replace `.subscribe()` to `.publish().connect()` like above, it will work correctly (no cancels)

```
const obs1 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/transitions`);
const obs2 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/states`);
obs1.publish().connect();
obs2.publish().connect();
```

Or if I merge two `Observables` to one and then get subscribed like above, it will work correctly too

```
const obs1 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/transitions`);
const obs2 = this.http.get(`${API_URL}/states`);
Observable.merge(obs1, obs2).subscribe()
```

**Why do I face this behavior? I need to understand, not bypass.** How can I make series of requests **without** merging, forking etc.?

Comment: I might be ok with bypassing, in which case, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found a potential reason of this behavior.

Thanks to https://github.com/ghetolay and https://github.com/dklmuc

We found out that angular will cancel very fast http requests which without any callback. So, you have to pass onNext in subscribe

From https://github.com/ghetolay:

> ok it's race condition I think
>
> it will always call xhr.abort() on teardown
>
> if the connection is still considered open by the browser it will close it, otherwise probably doing nothing
>
> so when you have a very fast handling of the response (like no callback is really really fast) it may abort the connection that's still considered open

This one works correctly:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${i}`).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(i, result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Now I feel bad, as I was going to comment about that but just assumed your example was simplified. If you need to execute a http request without a subscription. You can call `http.get(...).take(1)` which will subscribe and destroy the subscription after the first item is fetched.

Comment: @ctTag Is take(1) will invoke request event without subscribe method?

Comment: @ctTag No, it won't. Checked right now. But I've just realized that for http methods very logical to use `.take(1)`

Comment: Well thanks for citing me but this was just a wild guess. I since tried to repro your issue and wasn't able to. So I don't really know for sure what's going on.

Comment: This seems to be fixed by using HttpClient (Angular 4.3+)

Comment: I had the exact same problem in HttpClient in Angular 6.1.9 which I fixed with a swap from switchMap to mergeMap. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any example snippet for the solution ?

Answer (score 27):

This has to do with observables being cancelled, although I must admit I don't know the root cause for the problem you face.

I ran into a similar problem using the ngrx/effects module. The action handler made requests to a service using ngrx switch map operator. All except the last request would get cancelled. Changing it to merge map fixed the problem.
Below is the code

```
@Effect()
    loadSomeData$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
            .ofType(SomeActions.Load_Data)
            .mergeMap((id) =>
                    this.someService.getSomething(id)
                            .map((someEntity) => new SomeActions.LoadDataSuccess(someEntity)
                            ).catch((x, y) => {
                                    console.error('Error occured');
                                    return Observable.of(new SomeActions.LoadDataFailed(id));
                            }
                            ));
```

Reproducing the relevant part of ngrx here.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

> The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new observable.

Comment: I bumped into this problem today and now that I've read your reply I'm feeling rather foolish using a switchMap and then wondering why things get cancelled. I think I'll try using mergeMap! Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @JasonB Thanks for the mergeMap tip.  That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue in Angular v9. Switching to a mergeMap resolved the issue. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think its wrong to describe it as a "problem". First of all, its by design, as u quoted. In context of ngrx effects you tipically use a switchMap if u fetch data using the GET http method. A mergeMap is tipically used when u want to persist a lot of different data from different requests using the POST/PUT http method, same as exhaustMap and concatMap, whilst in latter case the order of data to be persisted is important. exhaustMap will only trigger a request when the latest has received a response. All other trials to send a request will be ignored.

Answer (score 20):

For me the problem was because of an empty observable.
I was using `Observable.forkJoin` on a list of observables.

**SOLUTION:** I needed to give my `Observable.of()` a value: `Observable.of(null)`

Comment: similar solution - each observables listed in my forkJoin need .pipe(catchError(() => of(null)));

Answer (score 3):

There may be multiple reasons for the HTTP requests to get cancelled. I have faced the same problem multiple times, So mentioning some of the methods that can help in fixing the issue.

1. If a component is destroyed before the HTTP API call is completed (example - Suppose we are calling an HTTP API in modal and if we are closing the modal component before HTTP call is completed)
2. While using fork-join(or a similar kind of operator) if one HTTP call is failed then other HTTP calls will be canceled.
3. If an HTTP API call is too fast then chrome will find it suspecious.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that routing will sometimes cancel all requests.  For example I route to /home but want to add a key in front so I route to /fred/home.   Chrome in it's wisdom cancels the pending tasks. leaving a half loaded system.

I had to put a 10 millisecond delay after redirecting using router

```
 this.router.navigate([event.value, 'home']);
// We have to wait for the actual navigation to complete or else chrome will cancel API calls.
timer(10).subscribe(() => {
  this.spaceSelectionService.setSpace(event.value);
});
```

of course under the covers the set space loads all sorts of configurations.   That tiny pause solved my problem.

Comment: Can it possible that you are using some autounsubscriber tools like https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy? They will cancel your request (the same way as they cancel any observable)

Comment: This is built into chrome itself.  I hand code my takeuntil code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something related to @Kevin Upton and @Mahesh mentioned in their answers. I am using Forkjoin in a list of observables also with Switch map. but one of them was returning undefined at some point. I didn't have to change Switch map to merge map. For me it was that ForkJoin needs all observables need to return something, at least:

**Observable.of(null)**