Subscription next(), error(), or complete() methods of http request not triggered when request times out
In my Angular + ngrx application, I have an @Effect triggered by an Action. Code is below
@Effect()
customAction$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<CustomAction>(Actions.CustomAction),
    tap(() => console.log('Custom Action was triggered')),
    switchMap((res) => {
        console.log('before http request...');
        this.myservice.DoApiCall().pipe(finalize(() => {
            console.log('finalize triggered...');
        })).subscribe(resultInner => {
                console.log('next() trigerred...');
                // other logic ....
            },
            () => {
                console.log('error() triggered...');
            });
        return EMPTY;
    })
);

My issue is when I have network troubles sometimes and the action is triggered (and then the http request tries to execute), the request fails to respond but neither error() method of the subscription is executed nor code in the finalize() operator. Is that even possible? I would guess that if a request fails to complete at least the finalize part should be executed always.
As already mentioned in the comments section and from @egorgrushin indeed subscribing into the inner observable of switchMap is not a good practice so I indeed returned the Observable of this.myservice.DoApiCall as shown below:
@Effect()
    customAction$ = this._actions$.pipe(
        ofType<CustomAction>(Actions.CustomAction),
tap(() => console.log('Custom Action was triggered')),
        switchMap((result) => {
            return this.myservice.DoApiCall().pipe(
                catchError((error) => {
                    // console.log('error caught');
                }),
                finalize(() => {
                    // console.log('finalize');
                })
            );
        })
    );

However the issue still seemed to be reproduced sporadically (when these network issues occurred).
I do not know if mergeMap would solve the issue but I preferred not to make use of it since I do want the inner observable to be cancelled if the outer observable of the chain gets triggered again (which happens because of the switchMap operator)
BYPASSING THE PROBLEM (NOT SOLUTION)
I managed to "bypass" the problem by chaining the timer operator in the http request inner observable using a quite big threshold (30s).
Now when the issue would be reproduced due to these network issues, these 30s will pass and the catchError block will be triggered.

It is probably the mergeMap causing this issue. Read this rxjs learn article about mergeMap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap. And also try catching the errors inside the switchMap.

Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. Do you mean i should use mergeMap instead of switchMap? Because as you can see currently I am using the latter, maybe the switchMap operator has cancelled an observable in the middle of it's execution so it never completes?

You should not subscribe, it's what switchmap is for here (unwrap an observable but cancel and start again if there's an emission upstream)

So what do you propose? return the inner observable of the 'this.myservice.DoApiCall()' instead of EMPTY and applying the // other logic.. through tap operator in the inner observable of the api request would be a good idea? If a second action triggers the effect the first observable will be canceled and it's finalize() method will be triggered?

You are probably facing the same issue I faced several years ago. This is a question and the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882434/2909375
Angular's http client sometimes doesn't call any rxjs callbacks in case of some network troubles or very fast requests.
Also, I would suggest to you to not subscribe inside effects. Instead, you have to return underlying observable:
@Effect()
customAction$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<CustomAction>(Actions.CustomAction),
    tap(() => console.log('Custom Action was triggered')),
    switchMap(() => this.myservice.DoApiCall().pipe(
        catchError(() => {
            console.log('error() triggered...');
            return EMPTY;
        }),
        finalize(() => {
            console.log('finalize triggered...');
        }),
    )),
);

I put nested pipe which is not necessary but will help you avoid logging at this._actions$ observable completion/error.
If you want your requests won't be canceled once you emit next action, you should replace switchMap to mergeMap.

Hello, thanks for your answer! As you can see I have updated the issue with what I did to bypass the problem. in the provided link I see most people suggest as a solution changing the switchMap operator with mergeMap (ideally I would not like to do that), is your suggestion the same?

@NickAth I suggest do not subscribe manually. Instead, just return inner observable as I have shown above

As you can see in the updated answer, I had already done that but problem seems to be irrelevant with the inner subscription as it still happened
